# Solving a recurrence relation with variable coefficients

Tags: recursion, difference-equations, inequalities

I am trying to solve this recurrence inequality for $ a_n $, hopefully in terms of $ a_0，a_1，c $ and $ x $,

$$(1-x)a_{n+1} \le xa_n + (1+x)a_{n-1} + c\quad\forall\ n\ge1$$

What I tried: RSolve. But RSolve expects an equality, and not an inequality. Any tips on how to proceed? $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$, $x\in\mathbb{Q}$, $c > 0$, $0 < x < 1$ and $a_i$ is not constant for all $i$.

Edit: I have some control over $x$ so I chose $x=1/2$ and used an equality instead of an inequality, then applied RSolve.

```
Simplify[RSolve[(1/2) a[n] == (1/2) a[n - 1] + (3/2)*a[-2 + n] + c, a[n], n]]
```

I got the result
$$a(n)\to c_1 \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(1-\sqrt{13}\right)\right)^n+c_2 \left(\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{13}+1\right)\right)^n-\frac{2 c}{3}.$$ However what I need is the inequality, and in terms of $x$. Do you know any other method in Mathematica available to do this?

Comment: As the error message says, RSolve is expecting an equation. You gave it an inequality. Change <= to == and it will return a result.

Comment: Hi, I am open to other ways to solve the recurrence without RSolve. I have searched but  I can't find the functions I need.

Comment: Thanks Bill, that works, but my problem is that $a$ is definitely not constant for all $n$ in my case.

Comment: Thanks. This is one step in some numerical analysis. I know that $a$ depends on $n$ i.e. $a_i$ is not constant for all $i$. I know that $x > 0$ and $c > 0$ while $n >= 1$. $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ while $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: `Simplify[Reduce[{(1-x)*a[n+1] <= x*a[n]+(1+x)*a[n-1]+c && x>0 && c>0}, x]]` Study that carefully and see how much you can extract from that or modifications of that.

Comment: Thanks again Bill. How can I constrain this result for all $a_k$ where $k \ge 1$? It seems to place conditions on the $a_k$ terms. When I added $n >=1$ I got the error that the system cannot be solved using methods available to Reduce.

Comment: I don't understand the problem yet. Let's take a simple special case, say a0=0 and a1=1. What kind of answer would you expect to see?

Comment: Something like $f(x)a_{n+1}+g(x)a_n \le p(x)a_1 + q(x)a_0 + r(x)c$ is what I expect to see, for some functions $f,g,p,q,r$. This is a simplified, smaller part of a numerical analysis problem. I have numerically shown that such a bound exists, but I am unable to prove it mathematically. I was hoping to get some more insight using Mathematica.